# Calling WebMethod in URL in Web Forms Asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, webmethod

I have tried Web Form application for the first time. My aim is to enable the URLS to call methods such as by typing http://localhost:51040/test.aspx/GetData on browser should call method GetData. Where GetData Method includes:

```
    [WebMethod()]
    public static string GetData()
    {
        person p = new person();
        Order o = new Order("gggg","fff",34);
        Database db = new Database();
        db.MakeOrder(o);

       // p.name = name;
        return p.name;
    }
```

I also tried Ajax function to call this method using POST request and it works when I click the button:

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
    $.support.cors = true;
]
$('#btn').click(function () {
    var name = $('#name').val();
   /// alert("The btn was clicked.");
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'test.aspx/GetData',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
       // data: "{'name': '" + name + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));


        }
    });
});

});
```

but I am still unable to call this method directly via  URL. I am so sorry if I did not deliver the complete information.However, if you need to know something else, I will try to provide you.
 I am anxiously waiting for helping reply.

Comment: Are you locked into using Web Forms? Why not use a modern framework like ASP.NET Web API?

Comment: I have already made the complete site. Now I need to demonstrate the CSRF in it for that i need to test if methods can be called on URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just need to add  `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]` attribute on GetData method.

Comment: it doesn't work. even the Ajax function also stopped working due to this

Comment: Have you tried debugging with developer tools from the browser? What does server reply when you issue get request?

Comment: it does nothing, just reload the page...no error message